# JQuery - Fazer o ENTER acionar um botão

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções, teclado

Tenho um código em JavaScript/JQuery que eu queria que também executasse a função ou ao clicar no botão, ou que o botão fosse acionado com o enter ao digitar. Detalhe que isso é só um teste que to fazendo, nada sério, não é um sistema de login nem nada disso. Segue o código:

```
$("#btIr").click(function(){
    const inLogin = $("#inLogin").val();
    const inSenha = $("#inSenha").val();

    if (inLogin === "admin" && inSenha === "jb2303") {
    window.location.href = "cadastro_de_produtos/index.html"

} else {
    alert("Login e/ou senha não conferem");
    $("#inLogin").focus();
    return
}

});
```

Como faço pra acionar a função pelo enter também?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geralmente, você pode usar o `event.keyCode === 13` para verificar se ENTER foi pressionado.

Você precisa usar o event `keydown`, `keyup` ou `keypress` para isso.

Exemplo:

```js
$('#input').on('keydown', function (e) {

  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log('Você apertou ENTER');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Mas também é possível simular isso se você tiver um `button` com o `type` igual a `submit` dentro de um `form`.

Aí basta capturar o event `submit` desse `form`, assim:

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  
  console.log('apertou o botão ou apertou enter');
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Aperte ENTER" />
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para acionar o evento de click de algo, use o método `.click()` do jQuery.

Exemplo:

```
if(event.keyCode === 13) {
  $('#btn').click();
}
```

Exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5pktmny8/2/)